# При наведении курсора на div1 открывать div2

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении курсора на `div1`, вместо него открывался `div2`?

Comment: `.div1:hover + .div2 {display: block;}` ?

Comment: I try it but don't work

Comment: Sorry, but you need to translate your question into Russian and show an example of your code. Otherwise, users will not answer your question.

Comment: I hope I made the translation most closely to original in terms of message significance.

Comment: Смысл переводить вопрос? Ведь не понятна суть вопроса.

Comment: Не понимаю, в чем проблема пойти на англоязычное сообщество...

Answer (score 1):

Например, через `selector1:hover+selector2`:

```css
.bg-green {background-color: green;}
.bg-red {background-color: red;}
.square {width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute;}

.container {position: relative;}

.b {display: none;}           /*B изначально скрыт*/
.a:hover+.b{display: block;}  /*показываем*/
.b:hover {display: block;}    /*сохраняем видимость */
```

```html
<h4>Показать блок B при наведении на блок A</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-red square a">Block A</div>
  <div class="bg-green square b">Block B</div>
</div>
```

---

через `opacity`:

```css
.bg-green {background-color: green;}
.bg-red {background-color: red;}
.square {width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute;}

.container {position: relative;}

.b {opacity: 0;}       /*B изначально скрыт*/
.b:hover{opacity: 1;}  /*показываем*/
```

```html
<h4>Показать блок B при наведении на блок A</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg-red square a">Block A</div>
  <div class="bg-green square b">Block B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А если по ДОМ `div2` находится по соседству слева? То не откроется. В таком случае только js?

Comment: "А если div2 нет в DOM - вообще беда." Можно менять порядок в DOM, модифицируя порядок отображения ..

Comment: Я вот сейчас подумал, что вопрос вообще не о том) Надо, наверное второй див **вместо** первого как-то показать.

Comment: В смысле модифицировать? То есть через js менять местами элементы по дом? Если так, то мало того, что вытекают проблемы с отображением (если элемент не абсолютно позиционирован или фиксирован), так это же тот же js, который более логично было бы использовать для того, чтобы дать листинг на ховер `div1` и ссылаться на `div2`, где бы он не был. Или я не так понял?

Comment: В смысле, в смысле? модифицировать порядок отображения можно разными способами от float c flex до translateX и rtl